# Sharepoint Web Templates and Publishing service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So its not recommended to ["Save site as template" with activated publishing feature](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature.aspx).

Cheat and go to the save web template or access it from SPD.

But is it ok to?

1. Build a template based on Team site.
2. Save it as template.
3. Then create a new site based on that template
4. Then activate the publishing feature.

Or

As far as I can see if you switch publishing off, you can then save the site as template.

Build a new team site, and then switch it back on again

Also tell me if I am wrong but the Content Query WebPart will not appear unless publishing is enabled at the site collection level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CQWP is only enabled for publishing sites.

The method you described is ok, but do not expect any publishing features to work in the restored template. For ex, you might have created pages based on some page layout. Those pages might be broken in restored template since page layouts is feature of publishing.

Comment: No Page layouts have been used they are just team site pages. So that should be ok.